# spring-rabbit client using lots of cpu

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am running a spring-boot application in ec2 on a c3.large machine.  It initializes a spring-rabbit client, which starts up its own thread.

After profiling my application using YourKit, I see that a lot of time is spent inside the rabbit client thread, inside: `com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run()` specifically down in `java.io.DataStream.readUnsignedByte()`

To me this looks like there is a while loop that continuously blocks on getting some input on a socket from the RabbitMQ server.

Has anyone run into this?  Am I reading the profiling results correctly?  Is there a way to make the amqp client be non-blocking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That code (`com.rabbitmq.client`) is in the underlying `amqp-client` (RabbitMQ Java client) code used by Spring AMQP.

> To me this looks like there is a while loop that continuously blocks on getting some input on a socket from the RabbitMQ server.

Yes, but when it blocks waiting for data, it does not use CPU - only when data is available does that method return. It's not spinning the cpu waiting for data.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.  I just wanted to clarify, YourKit shows lots of CPU time in that method - is it misinterpreting what is going on?

Comment: It does sound unusual. I'd have to look at the yourkit snapshot to comment further.

Comment: You might be looking at elapsed (wall) time (rather than cpu time) perhaps?

Comment: YourKit [defaults to wall time for IO methods](https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/times.jsp).